# NameError: name 'Post' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, python-3.5

In my admin.py, the line,

```
admin.site.register(Post)
```

gives the error:

```
NameError: name 'Post' is not defined
```

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `admin.py` you need to import `Post` from your models.

```
from .models import Post
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is unquoted; hence adding the method in quotes should work.

```py
admin.site.register('Post')
```

Comment: This is not correct and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just needed to change it to : request.method== 'POST':

Comment: Hello @Sofia-aoudjit, welcome to the Stackoverflow. please  make your a bit more comprehensive. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for tips on how to write a good answer.